# Safari on Mac HTML5 Drag and image event.dataTransfer.getData('text/html') is empty

Tags: javascript, html, safari, drag-and-drop

The title says most of it, but to see it in action, open this fiddle in Safari on a Mac - https://jsfiddle.net/ep2z5/6/

What happens in Chrome when I drag and drop an image(or a linked image) is that in my event handler, I can call `event.dataTransfer.getData( 'text/html' )` and I would get the complete HTML of the dragged element.

However this is not the case in Safari. In safari, I can only call `event.dataTransfer.getData( 'text' )` and this just gives me a URL. Which would probably work fine, if I wanted to drag plain `<img />` tags. However I need to be able to drag `<a><img /></a>` tags and when I do, I get the value of the `href` attribute and no information about the image.

It seems like it could be a bug, but I haven't found information about it anywhere.

The interesting thing is that if I drag an image from Chrome into Safari, then it works fine - go figure...

I thought that this could be a problem of protocols(https vs http), but you can reproduce the issue in the fiddle - which is literally the same document.

Comment: I can't seem to get the content even via `getData('text')`. Did you ever run into that @Nikola? Your fiddle doesn't work for me in Safari `11.0.2`